# Horizontal scrolling with pages and acceleration on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In native iPhone apps, you can scroll horizontally where every photo/page is locked when you scroll into/out of it .

Scrolling right less than a treshhold will accelerate back, and more than the treshhold will accelerate forward to next page and stop.

Is there a certain 'style' to just enable paging for mobile ?

To enable acceleration :

```
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

and the horizontal scrolling is using a scroller div with :

```
 overflow-x: scroll;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```